# MPI Slurm exit code 254?

Tags: c, mpi, slurm

I am attempting to run a C file using MPI. I'm still relatively new to MPI, and so I'm not sure what is going wrong. I'm trying to time how long it takes to do a function, to measure the speedup compared to a serial version. The timing code goes as follows:

```
int my_rank;
MPI_Init(0,0);
double start, elapsed, local_elapsed;
int iters; 
// compute page rank

start = MPI_Wtime();
iters = solve(S, C, d, y0, y, eps, strawman_mvpSM);
local_elapsed = MPI_Wtime() - start;
MPI_Reduce(&local_elapsed, &elapsed, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0,           MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(my_rank == 0) {
    printf("final (page rank) probabilities, %d iterations in time %f\n", iters, elapsed);
    printvec(y, n); printf("\n");
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

The code is compiled using `mpicc -g -Wall -std=c99 -o pagerank-mpi pagerank-mpi.c`

The code is run using `srun -n 2 ./pagerank-mpi 1000`

When this runs, I get the following as output:

```
[0] Abort: free_vbuf_head = NULL at line 175 in file vbuf.c
[1] Abort: free_vbuf_head = NULL at line 175 in file vbuf.c
initial probabilities
(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001,
0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, ), sum is 1
dimension is 1000, nnz is 9097, damper is 0.850000, epsilon is 1e-09

initial probabilities
(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001,
0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, ), sum is 1
dimension is 1000, nnz is 9097, damper is 0.850000, epsilon is 1e-09

srun: error: node25: tasks 0-1: Exited with exit code 254
```

I cannot find what exit code 254 means, and I don't know what vbuf.c is. The code fails to print the final probabilities, but prints the initial probabilities twice, something that it shouldn't be doing. My main concern is with the Abort lines and the exit code. Can anyone explain what those are doing and why?

Comment: `vbuf.c` is a part of uDAPL API implementation. Probably this one is a module from MVAPICH. Likely your MPI library is trying to initiate InfiniBand communication but fails due to misconfiguration. Also `MPI_Init(0,0)` is not a good idea -  the library might need the arguments supplied by the command line driver.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, ever since MPI-2.0 (introduced 18 years ago) the standard has mandated that compliant implementations should use a mechanism different than command-line arguments for passing MPI-specific information and should allow `MPI_Init()` to be called with two NULL arguments..

Comment: Make sure that `MPI_Init()` is not being called more than once.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you for the correction. Also should not one expect MPICH to simply terminate with `MPI_ERR_OTHER` if MPI_Init was called a second time?